# tkinter delete(0,END)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, user-input

I'm trying to clear the Entry widget after the user presses a button using Tkinter.

I tried using `EntryPlace.delete(0, END)`, but I got an error saying that strings don't have the attribute delete.

```
from tkinter import *

file=open(r'\Users\Armita\Desktop\new file\file_app.txt','a+')

def addline(): 
    file.write(user_entry.get() + '\n') 
    EntryPlace.delete(0, END)

def savechange(): 
    global file
    file.close() 
    file = open(r'\Users\Armita\Desktop\new file\file_app.txt', 'a+')

def saveandclose():
    file.close()
    top.destroy()

top = Tk() 
top.geometry('350x40') 
top.title('Tk')

user_entry = StringVar()
EntryPlace = Entry(top,textvariable=user_entry).grid(row=0,column=0)

AddButton = Button(top,text='add line',command= addline).grid(row=0,column=1)

SaveButton=Button(top,text='save changes',command= savechange).grid(row=0,column=2)

CloseButton1=Button(top,text='save and close',command= saveandclose ).grid(row=0,column=3)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
EntryPlace = Entry(top,textvariable=user_entry).grid(row=0,column=0)
```

You should declare the `Entry` and then add it to the `grid` on separate lines
like so:

```
EntryPlace = Entry(top,textvariable=user_entry)
EntryPlace.grid(row=0,column=0)
# now EntryPlace refers to the actual 'Entry' widget, and not 'None'!
```

Because `grid` returns `None`, as written `EntryPlace` will always evaluate to `None` and that can cause all kinds of problems.

The same behavior is true of all the geometry manager methods (`pack()`, `grid()`, and `place()`) so you should get into the habit of separating them from the widget declaration. You'll probably want to do this for all of your other widgets as well to prevent potential issues later.

I would also recommend looking into the [Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) for Python and perhaps using a linter like [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/). It will help you write better, more readable, and more standardized Python in the long run :)

(for example, `CapitalizedNames` are typically reserved for *classes* in Python, while variable names are usually written in `snake_case`)